# Index of the unit circle over the vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system 
$$\begin {cases}
\frac{dx}{dt} = 2x^2-1\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = 2xy
\end{cases}$$

Compute the index of the unit circle with respect to the vector field.

**My attempt:**
We can parametrize the curve using polar coordinates: $x = \cos \theta, y = \sin \theta$, then $\frac{dx}{dt} = 2\cos^2\theta - 1 = \cos2\theta$, $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2\sin\theta \cos\theta = \sin2\theta.$ How should I proceed?

The vector field:
[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by index?

Comment: @DavidJaramillo, Index of curve $C$ with respect to vector ﬁeld $(f, g)$ is $I(f, g, C) =$ number of times the vector turns counter-clockwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you go once around the unit circle ($\theta$ runs from $0$ to $2\pi$), the vector $(\cos2\theta, \sin2\theta)$ makes **two** full turns counterclockwise, therefore the index is $2$.

Comment: I added the vector field into my post, can you check it? So, basically from $[0, \pi],$ it makes one loop counterclockwise, and then from $[\pi, 2\pi]$ it makes another one, therefore the index is $2$, am I right?$

Comment: Yes, that's right. The part of the vector field that you drew doesn't really make sense, since all vectors start from zero. Only one vector in a vector field starts from the origin. You should have a collection of vectors starting from each point of the unit circle.